# Trying to convert PDF to JPG using Imagick

Tags: joomla-5.x

I have PDF documents created using FPDF and I wish to convert to jpg for displaying purposes.  I believe I have installed Imagick correctly and set the php.ini file to see it but when I try to suck it into my code I get the `Class "Imagick" not found`  error message.
Does this mean I haven't installed it correctly or is my code below not right?

```
    if (\file_exists($cert)) {
        
        $im = new \Imagick($cert.'[0]');
        $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        echo $im;

    }
```

As always any guidance appreciated.  I'm using php8.2 and I'm using WAMP on a windows machine.

Comment: The format looks to be okay. Have you run a phpinfo() against your environment to check if Imagick is installed and listed?

Comment: Yes I've checked that php has the extension set but when I run the above code I get the class not found message.  After reading all the instructions and hints/tips, I think I must have something wrong with my local path settings within WAMP so nothing to do with Joomla.  Sorry to be a nuisance.  I'll try my code on an active site to test.  Cheers.

Comment: Are you trying to run the above code from a Terminal,(CMD) as a CLI or part of Joomla instance? Using a Terminal or CMD command will use your Windows Path statements to find PHP which can be a different implementation of PHP to the one you have in your WAMP that is accessed via a CLI or Web url.

Comment: Ok, but no I'm using it in my Joomla! component.  My component creates a PDF certificate and I wanted to be able to display it as a thumbnail image.